# Given a constant object, how to create a type based on its values?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Considering the following use case

```
type Item = {
  key: string;
  type: string;
}
const Items = [
  { key: "label", type: "string" },
  { key: "value", type: "number" },
  { key: "name", type: "string" },
  { key: "required", type: "boolean" },
] as const satisfies Item[];
```

How to define a type that return the value of "key" as key and the value of "type" as type.

```
type t = {
  label: string;
  value: number;
  name: string;
  required: boolean;
}
```

Resolving the string doesn't seem to be a problem once I can handle that with:

```
type ArrayItem = (typeof Items)[number];
type ItemType<T extends ArrayItem['type']> = T extends 'string' ? string : T extends 'number' ? number : T extends 'boolean' ? boolean : never;
```

Any ideas?

I tried this, but it can't resolve the type individually.

```
type ExpectedType = {
  [key in ArrayItem["key"]]: ArrayItem["type"];
};
// returns: 
// type ExpectedType = {
//    label: string | number | boolean;
//    value: string | number | boolean;
// }
```

Comment: (note that `key` is a *type parameter* and should be written as one, such as `Key` or `K`) Are you just looking for key remapping as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w1GvGm)? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Why did you add `boolean` without adding the corresponding entry to `ItemType`? Is there a point to that?

Comment: That was my bad; it's fixed now. The idea was to expand the initial example to be more comprehensive.

Comment: Okay well I'll write up my answer when I get a chance. It's late in my time zone so it might not be until tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to iterate over any [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) (like `ArrayItem`) and then compute the desired key as well as the value from it:

```
type ExpectedType = {
    [T in ArrayItem as T["key"]]: ItemType<T["type"]>;
};
/* type ExpectedType = {
    label: string;
    value: number;
    name: string;
    required: boolean;
} */
```

---

As an aside: your `ItemType` code can be rewritten as a single [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) instead of a series of [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

```
type ItemType<T extends ArrayItem['type']> =
    { string: string, number: number, boolean: boolean }[T]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.4.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oG8BQVtQNYRAC4oBnYAJwEsA7AcwG4sdRJiyq7GBfDAYwHtqZWPAQkUUANpNsaPAWIAiADYBDAEYRligDRQWEJexq1FULjpnp5RKIoBuq5QFcIu-eEN3qzhJvJmFlZy+LaK1KoIbnoGRhQmgZY41qFK5BAAjs6U6QAm7rF26vz8yhCq1IkYALpQquICQsCkqsCUJABmlBDicIiS1YwYBlAAguTkqiB9SKgAFAb8HSKIJACUkj5+EOSDGMOeKwgAKp4APMdQEAAe8NS54uOT06KSAOQGb9UAfCjBpPE6GxAbQ9Ft-MRwTs9MVSuVqMRYWUKuZJMdqhgAPSYy43O4PKBvYx0N5QAD8AI4tCgxFxtwg93Ebyh5FJFJZNKgdPxTKR8LZUD5KMhEHsOyGIwAotdILx4LlTpAJJhkmioDQxhMpjM6uJjpJFKFFNVqsQZoqIBcDQZjd9uIxMQAqDxK6Wy+UW5VWNSaZTAqmMZKOFxeFmBnARKL+kzh7DpLI5CC5RElZHUbhQR2YoA)